# Segue from UITableView in Container to new UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to segue from a UITableViewController embedded in a Container, to another UIViewController. The issue is, Storyboard keeps resizing the new UIViewController to fit into the Container... I am pretty new to overriding the PrepareForSegue and others, and I have a feeling that is what I need to do...
[image: First attempt]

This is what I tried first, the segue to the SecondPracticeViewController is coming from the first cell on the UITableViewController static cell. Notice the SecondViewController gets resized to fit into the container.

I then set it up so the segue came from the PracticeTableViewContainer and titled the segue "SegueFromContainer"

[image: SegueFromContainer]

This is a screenshot of what I think I need to do. What do I need to do to get this to work? I don't know what exactly to override. Thank you very much!

Comment: What kind of segue are you trying to do? In your second picture, that segue to the full size controller can't be coming from the container view -- you can only have an embed segue from the container view, and the one you're showing is a push. That has to be coming from Practice Table View Container (which is the controller, not the container view).

Comment: You are right, it is coming from the PracticeTableViewContainer. PracticeTableViewContainer is a UIViewController embedded in a NavigationController. It has a Container with an embedded TableViewController. I can't get the segue from the TableViewCell -> the SecondPracticeViewController, because it always resizes it, so based on other posts, I am trying to get the PracticeTableViewContainer to recognize the TableViewCell interaction, and push segue to the SecondPracticeViewController.

Comment: The easiest thing to do, but I don't know if this is what you want, is to connect the table view cell to the SecondPracticeViewController by a modal segue. That will give you a full scale controller.

Comment: Ok great I'll look into that, but will that let me have it in my NavigationController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried something out, and found that if you do a push from the TableViewController, the SecondPracticeViewController shows up full scale, even though it looks small in IB. So, to fix that, you can change the size of that controller from "Inferred" to "Freeform" in the attributes inspector -- this will allow you to adjust the size of its view to be what ever you want, so you can layout the subviews visually.

Comment: Thanks! It does not seem to keep it in the Navigation Controller though... I need to be able to navigate back to the PracticeTableViewContainer ViewController.

Comment: @Siriss, Hmm.. worked fine for me. My set up was just like your first picture, except for resizing the SecondPracticeViewController. Do you not get a back button after you do the push?

Comment: I did not at first.... and after some troubleshooting I have to add ` self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;` to my ViewDidLoad for some reason. Any ideas why I suddenly have to do to that? It must be inherited at runtime but I can't see how.

Comment: No, I have no idea why. I didn't have to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I still don't know either.... starting over to find out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to do it the latter way that you mentioned in your question, you can override tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath in your tableViewController and call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.parentViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
}
```